# Scanner length don't match! java

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, string-length

The string variable `result` has the following string:

```
All Prime Numbers Up To {10}:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

When I use this code to scan each numerical token and return its length:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(result);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String num = scan.next();
            if (num.matches(".*\\d.*")) {
                System.out.print("number:     ");
                System.out.println(num);
                System.out.print("The length: ");
                System.out.println(num.length());
                System.out.println("----");
            }
        }
```

The result shows the following:

```
Please Enter a Number: 9
number:     {9}:
The length: 4
----
number:     1
The length: 1
----
number:     2
The length: 10
----
number:     3
The length: 10
----
number:     4
The length: 1
----
number:     5
The length: 10
----
number:     6
The length: 1
----
number:     7
The length: 10
----
number:     8
The length: 1
----
number:     9
The length: 1
----
```

Why it is not printing the correct length of each token of numbers? Even though it prints it correctly!

Comment: it seems something is wrong with your regex? or why do you need to use regex?

Comment: because I have a string and I want to return only numerical values @KickButtowski

Comment: what is the right regex that returns true if the next token is all numbers? So if a token is `{w10` it returns false @KickButtowski

Answer (score 1):

How do you initialize the variable *result*?

```
String result = "All Prime Numbers Up To {10}:\n1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
```

Using the init above I get a correct length of 1 for all numbers 1-9. I would use something like this:

```
String result = "All Prime Numbers Up To {10}:\n1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";

Scanner scan = new Scanner(result);
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        Integer num = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("number: "+num);
        System.out.println("The length: "+num.toString().length());
        System.out.println("----");
    }
    else {
        scan.next();
    }
}
scan.close();
```

Comment: Actually, you are right too. My code was correct, but the reason it didn't give me the exact length for all the prime numbers(if you noticed), is because I used this code `(char) 27 + "[31m" + "....prime number...." + (char) 27 + "[0m"` to print all prime numbers with the red color.

Comment: good point to use `hasNextInt()` instead of a regex for the same result

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason thanks to @KickButtowski.
The problem was with my regex.

I had to change it to the following: `"[0-9]+"` then it worked!

Even though my previous code was not wrong, this regex solved another problem I had in my code. If I used the regex `".*\\d.*"` it is going to return numbers that is mixed with characters, and I didn't want that.

Comment: but this regex means if you have any number that repeated one or more time, but what would happen if you have some alphabetical char in your string as well?